# Add Matrix and DiagonalMatrix in Eigen3

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, eigen3

I want to add elements to the diagonal of a Eigen::MatrixXd object with the Eigen3 library (version 3.3.2).

Both for optimisation and being able to use constness, I want to do this by adding a diagonal matrix to the original, like this

```
const MatrixXd a(2,2); a << 1, 2, 3, 4;
const VectorXd v(2); v << 10, 20;
const MatrixXd b = a + v.asDiagonal();
```

But this doesn't work: I get a compiler error about there being no `operator+`. Adding two `MatrixXd` does work, so I would expect it to behave for the diagonal specialisation.

Removing the constness doesn't help. Using statically sized matrices makes no difference, so it's not a dynamic-sizing thing. And explicitly constructing a `DiagonalMatrix` rather than using the `DiagonalWrapper` returned by `asDiagonal()` also gives the same error.

Multiplication *is* well-formed for these types: `MatrixXd c = a * v.asDiagonal();` compiles and runs just fine. Am I doing something wrong, or is `operator+(Matrix,DiagonalMatrix)` just missing from the library?

Comment: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=136617

Comment: Also related: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=610

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @CoryKramer for linking to an equivalent question being asked and answered on the KDE/Eigen forum: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=136617  Here's a summary for posterity:

"Normal" addition of an Eigen `Matrix` and either a `DiagonalMatrix` or `DiagonalWrapper` isn't a supported operation, while multiplication or compound `+=` addition are fine. `+=` isn't an option if trying to work with const objects, but constructing an explicit `Matrix2d` from the `asDiagonal()` call -- why didn't I think of trying that?! -- works nicely:

```
MatrixXd b = a + Matrix2d(v.asDiagonal());
```

I guess there are potential performance penalties, which is why this isn't supported without the type construction. But they're unlikely to be worse than the dirty alternative of manually looping over diagonal indices.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the KDE forum post is no longer available. In addition to what [@andybuckley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91808/andybuckley) shared, this solution may be more clear about the intention:

```
MatrixXd b = a + v.asDiagonal().toDenseMatrix();
```

This code creates a [DiagonalWrapper](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DiagonalWrapper.html) using vector v and then uses it to construct a DenseMatrix, which can be used in operations with other Matrices as desired.